# Getting title and description of embedded YouTube video 

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

On a site I'm developing I embed videos from YouTube and want to get the video title and its description.

How do I get that information?

Comment: I created a function to solve this in PHP here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13786724/1078904

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the **DESCRIPTION** element, you need to access the gdata version of the video's info, and you can return json using  alt=json on the path. In this case, **oHg5SJYRHA0** is the video ID, found at the end of the url of the video you're working with on YouTube, e.g. 
`www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0`

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/oHg5SJYRHA0?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true`

(the prettyprint is formatting to make that easy to read, you don't need it for what you're doing)

You can grab the JSON, add it into a variable and access it using jQuery:

```
var youTubeURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/oHg5SJYRHA0?v=2&alt=json';
var json = (function() {
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': youTubeURL,
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function(data) {
            json = data;
        }
    });
    return json;
})();
```

Then access it using object notation:

```
alert("Title: " + json.entry.title.$t +"\nDescription:\n " + json.entry.media$group.media$description.$t + "\n");
```

Comment: Is title and description attribute deprecated ? I'm getting  "https://youtube.com/devicesupport" values for both title and description.

Comment: @SheebanSingaram yikes. Yep, it looks like it, I'm seeing a deprecation warning on the YouTube API V2.0 Page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol. I'll have a look at this and update my answer.

Comment: pLease switch to API V3.0

Answer (score 15):

You can do it with [oembed](http://www.oembed.com/).
Example:

```
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DM3r2XDceM6A&format=json
```

Comment: Seems can't get the description.

Comment: Description is not included in the oEmbed data, as indicated on the documentation page you linked to. This answer does not address the question.

Answer (score 14):

**Youtube API V2.0** has been deprecated. It shows some wrong value for title **"youtube.com/devicesupport"** . Please switch on to **API V3.0**

You can refer to the following PHP code and modify yours in JS or jQuery as per your needs..

```
function youtube_title($id) {
 $id = 'YOUTUBE_ID';
// returns a single line of JSON that contains the video title. Not a giant request.
$videoTitle = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=".$id."&key=YOUR_API_KEY&fields=items(id,snippet(title),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics");
// despite @ suppress, it will be false if it fails
if ($videoTitle) {
$json = json_decode($videoTitle, true);

return $json['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
} else {
return false;
}
}
```

**update:**

jQuery code to get the title-

```
 $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={VIDEOID}&key={YOUR API KEY}&part=snippet&callback=?',function(data){
    if (typeof(data.items[0]) != "undefined") {
        console.log('video exists ' + data.items[0].snippet.title);
       } else {
        console.log('video not exists');
     }   
    });
```

Comment: what if you dont have an API key and want only title ?

Comment: in v2.0 it was possible, in v3.0 you need api key only.. and getting the api key is not difficult neither paid...

Comment: i got a solution, we can get title without API key... by using the below link http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoid&format=json ... but the thing is videoid should be known.

Comment: @PrashantBhujbal hi do you know how to decode the title if it's not in English? thank you!

Answer (score 5):

gdata is no longer available

you can use the following instead

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=(Video_ID)&key=(API_Key)

Answer (score 1):

I read this topic a bit in delay.
I did something like this using jSON and YT API's

```
$json = json_decode( file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$rs['vid']."?v=2&prettyprint=true&alt=jsonc") );
```

Note: $rs['vid'] is the video ID dinamically retrived from my DB.

Once you put the contents in the handle $json you can retrive like this:

```
$json->data->description;
$json->data->title;
```

use var_dump( $json ) to view all values you can access.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by taking a look at Youtube Data API to get what you want: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api

Answer (score -1):

GData is deprecated, but one can still get the video description by calling this endpoint:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=[video_id]&key=[api_key]

It will return a response of the form:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"...\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"...\"",
   "id": "...",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "...",
    "channelId": "...",
    "title": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "thumbnails": { ... },
    "channelTitle": "...",
    "tags": [ ... ],
    "categoryId": "...",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "...",
    "localized": {
     "title": "...",
     "description": "..."
    },
    "defaultAudioLanguage": "..."
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The description can be found at `items.localized.description`.