# Error in Getting Youtube Video Title, Description and thumbnail

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I was getting youtube title and youtube description form the same code but now its not working 
I am getting following error:

Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/colorsfo/public_html/zaroorat/admin/pages/addSongProcess.php on line 16

Warning: DOMDocument::load(http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Y7G-tYRzwYY) [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/colorsfo/public_html/zaroorat/admin/pages/addSongProcess.php on line 16

Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Y7G-tYRzwYY" in /home/colorsfo/public_html/zaroorat/admin/pages/addSongProcess.php on line 16

....................................
Following Coding is used to get Youtube Video Data:

`$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$embedCodeParts2[0];
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    @$doc->load($url);
    $title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $videoDescription = $doc->getElementsByTagName("description")->item(0)->nodeValue;`

It was working before (This coding is working fine in Local server but on internet its not working) but now its not working. Please guide me how to fix this error.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hello Muhammad, did any of the answers solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

Your server's allow_url_fopen is disabled (so is mine). I feel your pain. Here's what I did.

Try using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), but return your data in json, using YouTube's v2 api. You do that by appending that data to the end of your url.

```
?v=2&alt=json
```

You didn't post how you're getting your YouTube ID, and that may be a part of the issue (though your sample url did work). So just in case, I'm also posting a simple function to retrieve the ID from the YouTube video url.

```
function get_youtube_id($url) {
    $newurl = parse_url($url);
    return substr($newurl['query'],2);
}
```

OK, now assuming you have your video id, you can run the following function for each field you wish to return.

```
// Grab JSON and format it into PHP arrays from YouTube.
// Options defined in the switch. No option returns entire array
// Example of what the returned JSON will look like, pretty, here:
// http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/dQw4w9WgXcQ?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true
function get_youtube_info ( $vid, $info ) {
    $youtube = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$vid?v=2&alt=json";
    $ch = curl_init($youtube);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //If $assoc = true doesn't work, try:
    //$output = json_decode($output, true);
    $output = json_decode($output, $assoc = true);

    //Add the ['feed'] in if it exists.
    if ($output['feed']) {
        $path = &$output['feed']['entry'];
    } else {
        $path = &$output['entry'];
    }

    //set up a switch to return various data bits to return.
    switch($info) {
        case 'title':
            $output = $path['title']['$t'];
            break;
        case 'description':
            $output = $path['media$group']['media$description']['$t'];
            break;
        case 'author':
            $output = $path['author'][0]['name'];
            break;
        case 'author_uri':
            $output = $path['author'][0]['uri'];
            break;
        case 'thumbnail_small':
            $output = $path['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
            break;
        case 'thumbnail_medium':
            $output = $path['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][2]['url'];
            break;
        case 'thumbnail_large':
            $output = $path['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][3]['url'];
            break;
        default:
            return $output;
            break;
    }
    return $output;
}

$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0";
$id = get_youtube_id($url);

echo "<h3><a href=" . $url . ">" . get_youtube_info($id, 'title') . "</a></h3>"; //echoes the title
echo "<p><a href=" . $url . "><img style='float:left;margin-right: 5px;' src=" . get_youtube_info($id, 'thumbnail_small') . " /></a>" . get_youtube_info($id, 'description') . "</p>"; //echoes the description
echo "<br style='clear:both;' /><pre>";
echo print_r(get_youtube_info($id));
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Yes, you get extra points for the rick roll, and I love you - thankyou!

Comment: @WillLanni, if you see this, please may you tell me how i can shorten the descriptions instead of having the full description? thanks

Comment: User: I just had a look at the JSON returned from my example (see last line of comment, 4th line of my code example). There is a Description field, but you're basically limited to whatever you get from that. If you need to shorten the descriptions you'll need to write a custom function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

DOMDocuments' load() function uses PHPs fopen wrappers to retrieve files.
It seems that on your webserver, `allow_url_fopen` is set to 0, thus disabling these wrappers.
Try adding the following line to the top of your script:

```
ini_set ('allow_url_fopen', 1);
```

UPDATE: Try this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" . $embedCodeParts2[0];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$file = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($file);
$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$videoDescription = $doc->getElementsByTagName("description")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for Replying.
I tried this line of code but it did not work at all.
Please check this link where error exists

[link]http://www.colorsfocus.com/zaroorat/pages/allSongs.php

Comment: That probably means your host has disabled allow_url_fopen completely. Try using cURL (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to retrieve the file and then use the `DOMDocument->loadHTML()` function

Comment: I am not sure that how to use that can you please explain it to me with any example?
Thanks

Comment: Which webhosting are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not too late. My solution is to edit /etc/resolv.conf in your Linux machine: and replace first line with below line:

nameserver 8.8.8.8

Then save the file. no need for service restart.

Might work for servers who disabled some function accidentally for security.