# How to grab youtube title when embedding

Tags: javascript

I am using [ekko lightbox js](https://github.com/justinechacko/evergreenmalayalamsongs/blob/gh-pages/bs/assets/javascripts/ekko-lightbox.js) to show youtube videos in my website. I waould like to grab youtube title also. Author of this project ask me to put [this](https://github.com/abhinayrathore/jQuery-YouTube-Popup-Player-Plugin/blob/master/jquery.youtubepopup.js#L129) on `onNavigate` event of `ekko lightbox js`. How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting title and description of embedded YouTube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155029/getting-title-and-description-of-embedded-youtube-video)

Comment: I am not a coder can you explain how I can achieve it in ekko lightbox

Comment: Please correct this code, `<script>
    function getyoutubetitle(id) {
     var json = 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D' + id + '&format=json';
   document.write(json[title]);
    }
   </script>
getyoutubetitle(xh6mpAOD9ho);`